# All ways of testing a private method seem to fail (c#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I want to test this class with several very basic private (non static) methods, however...I cant seem to make it work.

The code below keeps giving me the following exception:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method 'GeneratorStandard.GetNumber' not found.

The test looks like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetNumber01()
    {
        var list = GetList();

        var generator = new GeneratorStandard();
        var privateObject = new PrivateObject(generator, new  PrivateType(typeof(Generator)));

        int result = (int)privateObject.Invoke("GetNumber", list);


        Assert.AreEqual(2, result);
    }
```

Generator is an abstract base class which contains the method and GeneratorStandard is an implementation class that inherits Generator.

I've also tried using the 'Create private accessor'-button in VS2010, however it only creates a Test Reference file but not an actual shadow-class...so that doesnt work.

Please help :)

Comment: Please define "fail."

Comment: was correcting the question while you were reading it I guess.

Comment: Is the fact that you can't access the private method a fail? Or is it a win for encapsulation!

Comment: Please see the question again, I've added the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If methods from abstract "base" class must be accessible through types inherithing from abstract class, they should be marked (at least) as `protected`, not `private`.

```
public abstract class MyClassBase {
   private void DoThis(){}
   protected void DoThat(){}
}

public class MyImplemntation : MyClassBase {

  //I don't know DoThis();
  //I know DoThat();
}
```

Comment: @NeedACar look at ISun's answer by the way, if you don't want to expose your methods to the inherited types.

Comment: I looked into that before asking, but without much success :)

Comment: @NeedACar it will also work (with the good flags). Now the choice  must really the answer to this question : should these methods be called by the inherited types, or not (not only for test) ?

Answer (score 2):

To invoke a private method via reflection you need to specify few [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
        var instance = new Foo();
        var type = instance.GetType();

        var meth = type.GetMethod("PrivateMeth", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if(meth != null)
            meth.Invoke(instance, new object[0] { });
```

`BindingFlags.NonPublic` defines that the member is not public.

`BindingFlags.Instance` defines that the member is not static.

Answer (score 1):

Look I'm not exactly sure If you're trying to invoke a private member and unit test it, however keep in mind that this is the wrong approach.

You should test your public methods and observe responses, communication and behavior. The private methods are just an implementation detail.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the whole debate on that :) In this case its not up to me though....

Comment: Sure :) I get it, np, this is more of a tip than an very concrete answer anyway :)

Comment: If you have too many (or sometimes even just any) private methods, the functionality within these private methods usually can be extracted into a reusable, testable class with public methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a c-c-c-combo breaker of dynamics and reflection (if this is .net 4 or better) to test your private method. Haven't played in this relm in a while but this should get you at least 80% there or better.
[Testing private methods with C# 4](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/05/testing-private-methods-with-c-40.html)
 And this might get you the rest of the way there as there. 
 [Use C# dynamic typing to conviently access internals of an object.](http://igoro.com/archive/use-c-dynamic-typing-to-conveniently-access-internals-of-an-object/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this article?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9715/How-to-Test-Private-and-Protected-methods-in-NET

In your code I'd say you have to first get the method through privateObject.GetType().GetMethod("GetNumber",flags) and then invoke it.